# Variational series , probability.

Tags: probability, random-variables

A Variation series is a series of random variables $Y_1,Y_2...Y_k$ where $k$ represents the $k-th$ largest random variable between $X_1, X_2...$, $X_i$ (independent of eachother , equally distributed). I found that the density function of $(Y_1, Y_n)$ is  $h(u,v)=\frac{n(n-1)}{(b-a)^2}(\frac{v-u}{b-a})^{n-2}$

How do I find: $EY_1Y_n$? It says here: (Which I don't understand )
$$ \frac{n(n-1)}{(b-a)^2}\int udu \int v (\frac{v-u}{b-a})^{n-2}dv$$

Can anyone explain this in more detail? Generally finding the expected value of a random vector peaks my interest aswell...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the joint density $h(u, v)$ of two random variables $(U, V)$ then you compute the expectation of their product as:
$$E[UV] = \int \int uv h(u, v) du dv$$

The integral you wrote above isn't quite right since you have an unbound $u$ inside the integral wrt to dv.  Plugging in $h(u, v) = \frac{n(n-1)}{(b-a)^2}\left(\frac{v-u}{b-a}\right)^{n-2}$ we get:

$$E[UV] = \int \int uv \frac{n(n-1)}{(b-a)^2}\left(\frac{v-u}{b-a}\right)^{n-2} du dv$$
where $U, V$ are your two random variables $Y_1, Y_N$.